# Different notion of isomorphism of topologies

Tags: general-topology

Is there a notion of isomorphism of topological spaces that captures the idea that open sets are in 1-1 inclusion preserving correspondence with each other, for example in this notion two indiscrete spaces no matter the size of their underlying sets are isomorphic?

Comment: You mean that $\langle X,\tau_X\rangle$ and $\langle Y,\tau_Y\rangle$ are ‘equivalent’ if the partial orders $\langle\tau_X,\subseteq\rangle$ and $\langle\tau_Y,\subseteq\rangle$ are isomorphic?

Comment: @BrianM.Scott yes

Comment: You should search for "Pointless Topology".  This is the study of "frames" and "locales".  The Wikipedia page has lots of info.

Comment: @Ruy That should be an answer.

Comment: Ok @Noah, since you and 2 others think so, it's done!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should search for "Pointless Topology". This is the study of "frames" and "locales". The Wikipedia page has lots of info: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pointless_topology